# Azure AD App-Only for SharePoint without granting broad tenant permissions

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

I would like to set up an Azure AD App-Only for accessing a certain site in SharePointOnline. However, when you set up the Azure AD App-Only application, it seems you can only give it access across ALL sites site collections and cannot not be selective on scope. Is there a better way to do this without granting broad access?

Should I be using SharePoint App-Only application instead using the xml definition for permissions? I know using this approach you can limit it to just a site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: You can limit access to a SharePoint site collection in the application context by using the **`Sites.Selected`** application permission but you cannot restrict access to specific folders/files or specific scope.

Created Azure AD Application and granted API permission:

[image]

**To grant access to only one SharePoint site**, I used the below PowerShell script:

```
$siteUrl = “https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk”
$clientId = “ClientID” 
$certThumbprint = “Thumbprint” 
$tenant = “xxx.onmicrosoft.com”

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions “Write” -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName “PowerShell-SharepointOnline”
$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $clientId
Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions “FullControl”
```

[image]

I am able to access the site when SharePoint site using application:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

[image]

When I tried to access another SharePoint Site, got 403 **forbidden** error:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

[image]

- Microsoft Graph API permissions are tenant wide and cannot be restricted to the specific scope.
- Full level access permissions are given to the Azure AD App if the app has been granted application permissions.
- Hence, you can restrict the SharePoint collection site only but not restrict to the scope.

*To confirm the above, check the below* **references:**

[How to allow my app without user to access ONLY specific drive or folder - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/673127/how-to-allow-my-app-without-user-to-access-only-sp)  by Vasil Michev

[Graph API - Restrict OneDrive/Sharepoint Access when using "Files.ReadWrite.All" and "Sites.ReadWrite.all" Permissions - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1139865/graph-api-restrict-onedrive-sharepoint-access-when)  by CarlZhao-MSFT

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and report back. I was not aware of the possibility to limit it to a Site Collection. Appreciate it!

Comment: This worked as expected. Thanks for the solution!