# Which Authentication Flow to use for Daemon app that must impersonate a user in order to use delegated permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, sharepoint-online

Q1. Which Authentication Flow to use for Daemon app that must impersonate a user in order to use delegated permissions?

Q2.Does Sharepoint Online have additional fine grained permissions that would allow us to use App-Only access and still consider the solution to be as secure as possible?

**Duplicate assessment:** There are a couple of 6 year old questions and the flows have changed in the meantime so a more ideal option may exist now in 2023.

**Context:**
I am working on a high security external integration to sharepoint. The integration service will be hosted externally to the sharepoint tenant and will be running either as an azure function or a web api service depending on how it grows.

Ordinarily for this type of service one would choose the [Client Credentials Authentication Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-authentication-flows) however the API Permissions (Application permissions level) for Sharepoint are wildly excessive to the point that they are extremely unsecure given the service is hosted external to the sharepoint instance and under different ownership. The equivalent Graph API permissions are even worse.

[image: Application level permissions]

The required permissions are simply to read and write files in one site which is very constrained and would fit neatly into the delegated permissions for a user authenticated application. However being a service it has no user interaction.

[image: Delegated Permissions]

Ideally we would have a dedicated integration user belonging to the target Sharepoint Online site so that the site owner could appropriately constrain the permissions at their end.

At the moment the only functional Auth mechanism seems to be username password where we store the password but that just feels inappropriate in this day and age.

I'm new to sharepoint online integrations specifically so i'm not sure if the "Application Permissions" can be subjected to additional constraints within Sharepoint Online for the Registered Application or is it stuck with what is requested during the configuration in Azure portal?

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: You can make use of On-Behalf of flow. This flow allows your daemon app to obtain an access token for a web API by exchanging a user's access token. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

For sample, I created a webapp:

[image]

Created a SharePoint app:

[image]

To authorize users, I used below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=webappclientid
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://xxx/Sharepoint.Access
&state=12345
```

[image]

Generated access token:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:webappClientID
scope:api://xxx/Sharepoint.Access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Now by using the above access token, **I called SharePoint API using OBO flow** on behalf of user:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:SharePointappClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:accesstoken
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
scope:https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/.default
```

[image]

Granting application Api permissions to an external service hosted outside of SharePoint Online is risky. Hence make use of delegated Api permissions.

**Reference:**

[Azure AD App-Only for SharePoint without granting broad tenant permissions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77176645/azure-ad-app-only-for-sharepoint-without-granting-broad-tenant-permissions/77177037#77177037) by me

Comment: I appreciate the effort put in to this answer but from reading through it the answer is still that it's not possible.

Not all web service API's are user facing which is the problem.

Comment: I appreciate the effort put in to this answer but from reading through it I can see that the answer is still that it's "not possible".

Not all web service API's are user facing which is the problem. Your suggested solution requires a user facing web app as an intermediary.

I'll have a look at the App Only link you included to see if that will achieve our goals but it may be too complex for the owners of the sharepoint instance to implement.

So it seems that the solution is to still store the password of the "service user" and authenticate as them using the username/password flow.

Comment: Do you want to implement ROPC flow?

Comment: Yes and no...
If you check the diagram in their documentation...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth-ropc
It requires the user.
However... replacing the user with say a keyvault secret for the password effectively achieves the same flow.

Comment: Afaik that is not possible