# Setting Access Policies/Scoping for MS Graph API Application permissions for Files (Files.ReadWrite.All)

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have an application with delegated permissions that currently can send emails via a logged in user and can also read and write to the users onedrive or onedrive folders shared with the user (currently all files are stored in a folder shared among users). However, we want to move to application permissions so our application can send emails from a shared mailbox without a user logged in and also do file reading/writing while a user is not logged in. I have found MS instructions to set access policies so only certain mailboxes are accessible by an application however I am not seeing anything in regards to the Files permission. How can we restrict this permission to only a specified group or some sort of access control so this application cannot Read and Write across all users in the tenant but limited to a shared folder. (We have setup a application permissions/service account with Box and the app is treated like its a user basically so we shared access to a folder with this service account and it was super easy however I am not sure if applications work similarly for Azure).

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77176645/azure-ad-app-only-for-sharepoint-without-granting-broad-tenant-permissions/77177037#77177037

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: You cannot restrict access to specific drive files or folders or at a specific scope, it is possible restrict which Site collections or drives can be accessed. Refer this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/673127/how-to-allow-my-app-without-user-to-access-only-sp)  by Vasil Michev.

- I agree with you, you can limit or restrict the application to access to certain mailbox by creating the Application Access Policy but setting this policy supports only for (*Mail.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.ReadWrite, Mail.Send, MailboxSettings.Read, MailboxSettings.ReadWrite, Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite, Contacts.Read, Contacts.ReadWrite*).
- Hence, access policy is not supported for Files permission.

**As User's OneDrive is also one of the SharePoint sites, you can try the below workaround:**

Initially fetch the SharePoint Site ID of required OneDrive by using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/{server-relative-path}`. Refer this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/698849/onedrive-api-restring-folder-file-access) by *JanardhanaVedham-MSFT* .

Grant **`Sites.Selected`** application permission:

[image]

Use the below PowerShell script to grant access to only one site:

```
$siteUrl = “https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testruk”
$clientId = “ClientID” 
$certThumbprint = “Thumbprint” 
$tenant = “xxx.onmicrosoft.com”

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive
$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions “Write” -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName “PowerShell-SharepointOnline”
$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $clientId
Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions “FullControl”
```

[image]

Using the application, I am able to access the site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
```

[image]

If the application tries to access another Site, 403  **forbidden** error will be triggered:

[image]

- If the application is granted with Microsoft Graph files application permission (Files.ReadWrite.All), then the application is granted with tenant wide access, and they cannot be restricted.
- Hence try to restrict access to the site.

*To set access policy for mailbox **refer** below MsDoc:*

[Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

Comment: When you register an app in azure does it act as a service account which a user can share a onedrive folder with it and I just need to find the name of the application service account similar to my box reference I indicated above? I am not as familiar with sites which you have used that previous answer and I am not sure how it would work for my use case.

Comment: Do you want to restrict Files.ReadWrite.All application permission to one shared folder?

Comment: Yea if that is possible its exactly what I am trying to do. Really the application just needs to save to a onedrive folder. Right now I have on for my own user and I have delegated permissions so its easy to save to it since I am the user and I have shared access to the folder iwth my other users so their delegated permissions also give access then. However, really I just need the application to save to a folder and I can always share it with users if they ever want to access it outside of the app on say onedrive online.

Comment: It is not possible to restrict files.readwrite.all api permission. As described in my answer "If the application is granted with Microsoft Graph files application permission (Files.ReadWrite.All), then the application is granted with tenant wide access, and they cannot be restricted"